# CSS: placing absolute positioned element so that it touches its parent from outside

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

I want the absolute positioned child touch its parent from outside like this:

```css
.parent {
  background: #aaffaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: #ffaaaa;
  width: 100px; // actually unknown, here for demo purposes
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The problem: I can't use the `transform` property, because it's already in use in a keyframe animation, the element may or may not be `position: absolute`. Is there some elegant solution to this?

Comment: Indeed you CAN use transform.  You just include the other transforms into a single declaration, eg `transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);`  HOWEVER, if you know the child is 100px wide, why not `left: -100px`?

Comment: @cale_b, firstly, I set it to be 100px wide just for example, in real it doesn't hjave fixed width. Secondly, The other transform declaration is in the animation, so I would have to douvle the animation declaration

Comment: Let this be a lesson that _details matter_.  See  one of my [favorite move scenes](https://youtu.be/qHDSNs9wBpU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is! There is just 1 line missing in your code.
You just need to use **right:100%** and it will be just fine.

```css
.parent {
  background: #aaffaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: #ffaaaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Oh, that was such an obvious solution, I don't know how I didn't came up with it myself. That's perfect, thank you very much

Comment: To be clear - not _one line missing_ - but _one line to change_.  Can't keep the `right` AND `left` declarations, otherwise it'll give undesirable results :)